# GridView not refreshing after Delete event

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview, refresh

I am having a strange problem with asp.net `GridView`. I have `GridView` that is bound to a `LinqDataSource`. On `GridView`'s row deleting event, I am deleting the row from database, but the grid is not refreshed, (even after BINDING to the datasource).

When I put a breakpoint, I could see the `OnRowDeleting` event is fired after the `LinqDS_Selecting` event. But its not fired again after the delete event! Could that be the reason? What am I doing wrong?

Could some one please help. Many thanks in Advance.

.aspx file:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource
    ID="LinqDS"
    runat="server"
    OnSelecting="LinqDS_Selecting">
</asp:LinqDataSource>

<asp:GridView
    DataSourceID = "LinqDS"
    ID = "gv1"
    runat = "server"  
    DataKeyNames = "InstructionId"
    EnableViewState = "false"
    OnRowDataBound = "gv1_RowDataBound" 
    OnRowDeleting = "gv1_RowDeleting" 
    OnRowCommand = "gv1_RowCommand"
    PageSize = "30" >
    <Columns>
        <!-- My colums --->
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void LinqDS_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    // my linq to sql query
    var query = from  .... .... ;
    e.Result = query;
}

protected void gv1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int instructionId = (int)gv1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
    /// my delete logic
    CTX.SubmitChanges();
    gv1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Did the `gv1_RowDeleting` fired ? If yes maybe you also need to make `LinqDS.DataBind()` ?

Comment: Does the gv1_RowDeleting event fire and is the value you're trying to remove actually removed from the database?

Answer (score 1):

If your record is actually deleted correctly and the grid is simply just not showing the changes I would try and put the GridView inside an UpdatePanel and see if this helps.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        // GridView
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't point out error in your code but I am giving you my code which i did to delete the data.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="Del" DataKeyNames="Clg_ID" BackColor="#DEBA84" 
                BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
                CellSpacing="2">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

.cs file

```
protected void Del(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        string i = GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString();
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from Feedback where Clg_ID='" + i + "'", cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        cn.Close();
        Response.Redirect("MFeedback.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `EditIndex` of the GridView to -1 on the `ItemDeleting` method of the GridView :

```
protected void gv1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) {
    gv1.EditIndex = -1;
    gv1.DataBind();
}
```

and moving your delete logic to the `RowCommand` method of the GridView:

```
protected void gv1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) {
    If (e.CommandName == "Delete") {
        int instructionId = (int) gv1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
        /// my delete logic
        CTX.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Your control for the delete action should be something like:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbDel" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />
```